# how to make input box height to grow as input exceeds the width

Tags: html, css

I have a little OpenAI web app project and it has one input box and a submit button in a form, which gets input and post it to the app and then get the answer.

I want the input text field to grow in height as users' input exceeds the width of input field. I've find some solutions like changing it into a textarea but I'm not really into web app development so I don't know what to change in app.py or main.css

As I undestand contenteditable or resizable doesn't work anymore.

Is there really no way of applying this without changing the input field into textarea? If there is, I would love to learn, thanks!

Here is my code:

main.css

```
body,
input {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #353740;
  font-family: "ColfaxAI", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 320px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #10a37f;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  align-self: center;
  width: 500px;
}
::placeholder {
  color: #8e8ea0;
  opacity: 1;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 12px 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #10a37f;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.result {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

index.html

```
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="Describe your task in details" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Generate function" />
  </form>

  {% if result %}
  <div class="result">{{ result }}</div>
  {% endif %}
```

app.py

```
@app.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        task = request.form["task"]
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-001",
            prompt=generate_prompt(task),
            temperature=0,
            max_tokens=200,
            top_p=1,
            frequency_penalty=0,
            presence_penalty=0
        )
        return redirect(url_for("index", result=response.choices[0].text))

    result = request.args.get("result")
    return render_template("index.html", result=result)
```

Comment: `input` is not intended to contain multiple lines. If you want something theat increases ithe height to wrap the text into new lines then you should use a `textarea`. Everything else would be a mis-used hack that relies on the browser auto-correction feature. Whatis so difficault that it prevents you to `<textarea></textarea>` instead of `<input>`?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm not familiar of using textarea I don't know how to refer it in css and I don't know if I have to change anythin in py file after I change the input to textarea that's why I'm afraid to use it. But I didn't know it was impossible with input and other solutions were using browser features, so I'm just gonna try it